# Structural Changes in Short-Term Time-Series

Tags: time-series, structural-change

I am dealing with a time-series consisting of 20-second observations over a 24-hour period (4320 observations). I'm wondering if it is sensible to characterize significant shocks (such as an important news event) as structural changes, even if it only applies to a single day data. Or are structural changes strictly macroeconomic phenomena?